# Python, ctypes, How to fix: OSError: exception: access violation writing 0x0000000000000000

Tags: python, dll, anaconda, spyder, ctypes

I am trying to configure the connection of Python program with the trading terminal(QUIK) using this official dll: http://arqatech.com/upload/iblock/80a/Trans2QuikAPI_1.3_x64.zip .
There is no convenient connection for this dll with python, but I found a python wrapper written 10 years ago for this dll of the previous version: https://pypi.org/project/PyQUIK/ .
The previous versions of the dll were 32 bit, and the new 64 bit, the old versions did not start at all, when I tried the new version of the dll, it worked, but it constantly gives errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "_ctypes/callbacks.c", line 232, in 'calling callback function'

OSError: exception: access violation writing 0x0000000000000000
```

The error occurs only when the trading terminal that the dll is trying to connect to is ready to accept transactions from the dll. When the terminal does not accept transactions, no errors occur. In this case, errors occur at the stage of connecting to the terminal, and when the connection with it is stopped. The error messages say about ctypes, but I am not familiar with either this library or the C language, so I don’t know how to fix this problem. 
Here is the part of the code that causes the error:

```
from ctypes import WinDLL, c_char, c_long, c_double, POINTER, \
     WINFUNCTYPE, byref, create_string_buffer, pointer, string_at
from ctypes.wintypes import LPCSTR, LPSTR, DWORD, CHAR, PDWORD
from ctypes.util import find_library

c_long_p = POINTER(c_long)
c_double_p = POINTER(c_double)
c_void = None


try:
    TRANS2QUIK = WinDLL("TRANS2QUIK.dll")
except OSError:
    import os
    libpath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "TRANS2QUIK.dll")
    TRANS2QUIK = WinDLL(libpath)


pnExtendedErrorCode_data = c_long()
pnExtendedErrorCode = byref(pnExtendedErrorCode_data)
pnReplyCode_data = c_long()
pnReplyCode = byref(pnReplyCode_data)
pdOrderNum_data = c_double()
pdOrderNum = byref(pdOrderNum_data)

dwErrorMessageSize = DWORD(200)
dwResultMessageSize = DWORD(200)
lpstrErrorMessage = create_string_buffer(dwErrorMessageSize.value)
lpstrResultMessage = create_string_buffer(dwResultMessageSize.value)


def _declare_extended(func, *args):
    func.restype = c_long
    func.argtypes = args + (c_long_p, LPSTR, DWORD)
    def __caller__(*args):
        args += (
            pnExtendedErrorCode,
            lpstrErrorMessage,
            dwErrorMessageSize
        )
        return func(*args)
    return __caller__


def _declare_method(func, restype, *args):
    func.restype = restype
    func.argtypes = args
    return func


# long TRANS2QUIK_CONNECT(
#     LPCSTR lpcstrConnectionParamsString,
#     _________________________
#     long* pnExtendedErrorCode,
#     LPSTR lpstrErrorMessage,
#     DWORD dwErrorMessageSize
# )
CONNECT = _declare_extended(
    TRANS2QUIK.TRANS2QUIK_CONNECT, LPCSTR
)

def connect(path):
    lpcstrConnectionParamsString = LPCSTR(path.encode())
    return CONNECT(lpcstrConnectionParamsString)

# long TRANS2QUIK_DISCONNECT(
#     _________________________
#     long* pnExtendedErrorCode,
#     LPSTR lpstrErrorMessage,
#     DWORD dwErrorMessageSize
# )
disconnect = DISCONNECT = _declare_extended(
    TRANS2QUIK.TRANS2QUIK_DISCONNECT
)

connection = connect("C:\SBERBANK\QUIK")
print(connection)
disconnect = disconnect()
print(disconnect)
```

I use python version 3.7.6, library ctypes version 1.1.0, windows 10 64 bit

I have experience in python programming for about a year, I'm not a professional in English either, so sorry if something is wrong, this is the fault of Google translator.

Comment: That's a classic null pointer dereference. Can you extract and provide a [mcve]? The fault should become more or less obvious then. As a new user, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: The problem is that the Error only occurs if there is a trading terminal receiving a command from the dll, without a trading terminal an error cannot be reproduced.